# KioskMode in React Native and Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, react-native, kiosk-mode

How can I set up KioskMode using ReactNative in a tablet with Android 4.4.4?

I have tried all of these below but none of them worked:

- https://medium.com/@aeperea/setting-up-an-android-app-with-react-native-in-kiosk-mode-e062b309db71
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-kiosk-mode
- https://github.com/fast0490f/react-native-lock-task

I'm still able to exit the app pressing the Home Button and interact with the StatusBar swiping down the area above the screen.

I think that is something about the version of Android used (4.4.4).

The main functions I need to implement are blocking the Home Button and StatusBar, the rest of KioskMode functions are not that important on this project.

Comment: Can anyone, please, help me?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Still no solution.

Comment: I am also looking for the solution